# Replace string value with '0' when string is empty

Tags: c#, replace, converters, string

I'm taking a value from a textbox and converting it to decimal. But, the textbox value could be empty. So, how could I handle empty strings from the textbox?

Unfortunately I have around 50 textboxes to deal with, so answers like 'check for null with IF condition' won't help me. My code will look ugly if I use all those IF conditions.

I have this

```
Convert.ToDecimal(txtSample.Text)
```

To handle nulls, I did this

```
Convert.ToDecimal(txtSample.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSample.Text) ? "0" : txtSample.Text)
```

But, the above code is displaying '0' in the textbox. User does not want to see '0'. Another solution is to take text box value into a variable and convert the variable like below.

```
string variable = txtSample.Text;
Convert.ToDecimal(variable = string.IsNullOrEmpty(variable) ? "0" : variable)
```

But again, I do not want to define around 50 variables. I am looking for some piece of code that handles null values during conversion without adding the extra line of code.

Comment: What type of app is this? WPF? ASPNET? The reason I ask is becuase a WPF app has [Value Converters](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) that make this super easy.

Comment: +1'd the post to offset a spurious -1(?). Dunno why people still -1 posts without a reason... c'mon folks...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> But, the above code is displaying '0' in the textbox. User does not want to see '0'.

This is because your statement is assigning the new value to `txtSample.Text` (when you do `txtSample.Text = ...`). Just remove the assignment:

```
Convert.ToDecimal(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSample.Text) ? "0" : txtSample.Text)
```

To make things easier if you have many text fields to handle, you can define an extension method :

```
public static string ZeroIfEmpty(this string s)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? "0" : s;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Convert.ToDecimal(txtSample.Text.ZeroIfEmpty())
```

Comment: lol..I am feeling like an idiot after reading your answer. haha. Why did I assign the value to the textbox in the first place? and when the problem was obvious why was I not thinking of removing the assignment? What the hell have I been thinking for 2 hours to fix this? haha. I think my programming part of brain was shut down and I was thinking with other parts of the brain. :) . Anyway, thanks mate.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a function to keep from copying the code all over the place.

```
decimal GetTextboxValue(string textboxText)
{
    return Convert.ToDecimal(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textboxText) ? "0" : textboxText);
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
GetTextboxValue(txtSample.Text);
```

Comment: nice one mate. I ll do this. But I cannot mark it as answer beacuse I already did that to another answer.

Comment: Good answer. Replace the (variable) to (textboxText) on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method for the string as below

```
        public static decimal ToDecimal(this string strValue)
        {
            decimal d;
            if (decimal.TryParse(strValue, out d))
                return d;
            return 0;
        }
```

Then you can just txtSample.Text.ToDecimal() in every place.